# Recursively Creating a Binary Tree Given a String Expression in Prefix Notation in Python

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree, prefix

[Representation of LinkedBinaryTree that should be outputted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DXNJ.png)
    import LinkedBinaryTree

```
def create_expression_tree(prefix_exp_str):

    def create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos):
        start_pos += 1
        op = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
        elem = prefix_exp[start_pos]
        if elem == ' ':
            elem = prefix_exp[start_pos+1]
            start_pos += 1

        if elem not in op:
            return LinkedBinaryTree.LinkedBinaryTree.Node(int(elem))
        else:
            left = create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos)
            right = create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos+2)
            return LinkedBinaryTree.LinkedBinaryTree.Node(elem, left, right)

    tree = LinkedBinaryTree.LinkedBinaryTree(create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp_str, -1))

    return tree

tree1 = create_expression_tree('* 2 + - 15 6 4')
for i in tree1.preorder():
    print(i.data, end='')
```

I implemented my own binary tree class which is shown below. Preorder() is a generator for my LinkedBinaryTree that gives the values of the tree in prefix order. With this code, I'm outputting
*2+-151
but it should be outputting
*2+-1564 if the binary expression tree has been created correctly.
I'm aware that there is an issue with numbers greater than 1 digit, but I'm not sure how to fix it without compromising the runtime (ie. using slicing). Also I'm not sure why it is omitting some of the tokens. Any ideas? (The implementation must run in linear time and use no additional parameters in the helper function I've defined).

```
import ArrayQueue

class LinkedBinaryTree:

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
            self.data = data
            self.parent = None
            self.left = left
            if (self.left is not None):
                self.left.parent = self
            self.right = right
            if (self.right is not None):
                self.right.parent = self

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root
        self.size = self.subtree_count(root)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self) == 0

    def subtree_count(self, root):
        if (root is None):
            return 0
        else:
            left_count = self.subtree_count(root.left)
            right_count = self.subtree_count(root.right)
            return 1 + left_count + right_count


    def sum(self):
        return self.subtree_sum(self.root)

    def subtree_sum(self, root):
        if (root is None):
            return 0
        else:
            left_sum = self.subtree_sum(root.left)
            right_sum = self.subtree_sum(root.right)
            return root.data + left_sum + right_sum


    def height(self):
        return self.subtree_height(self.root)

    def subtree_height(self, root):
        if (root.left is None and root.right is None):
            return 0
        elif (root.left is  None):
            return 1 + self.subtree_height(root.right)
        elif (root.right is  None):
            return 1 + self.subtree_height(root.left)
        else:
            left_height = self.subtree_height(root.left)
            right_height = self.subtree_height(root.right)
            return 1 + max(left_height, right_height)


    def preorder(self):
        yield from self.subtree_preorder(self.root)

    def subtree_preorder(self, root):
        if(root is None):
            return
        else:
            yield root
            yield from self.subtree_preorder(root.left)
            yield from self.subtree_preorder(root.right)


    def postorder(self):
        yield from self.subtree_postorder(self.root)

    def subtree_postorder(self, root):
        if(root is None):
            return
        else:
            yield from self.subtree_postorder(root.left)
            yield from self.subtree_postorder(root.right)
            yield root


    def inorder(self):
        yield from self.subtree_inorder(self.root)

    def subtree_inorder(self, root):
        if(root is None):
            return
        else:
            yield from self.subtree_inorder(root.left)
            yield root
            yield from self.subtree_inorder(root.right)


    def breadth_first(self):
        if (self.is_empty()):
            return
        line = ArrayQueue.ArrayQueue()
        line.enqueue(self.root)
        while (line.is_empty() == False):
            curr_node = line.dequeue()
            yield curr_node
            if (curr_node.left is not None):
                line.enqueue(curr_node.left)
            if (curr_node.right is not None):
                line.enqueue(curr_node.right)

    def __iter__(self):
        for node in self.breadth_first():
            yield node.data
```

I added the code here for LinkedBinaryTree class. The ArrayQueue class that is used in the implementation of the breadth traversal method is just a basic queue using a Python list as the underlying data structure.

Comment: Hi Kevin Chang, it is quite difficult to know what is going wrong without access to your `LinkedBinaryTree` class... do you have a GitHub repo or something?
Otherwise at least give us the exact output from your terminal, and try to explain what the Nodes you add to your Tree are supposed to look like.

Comment: I uploaded my LinkedBinaryTree class as you've requested. Also, there is now a photo attached that shows the binary tree that should be created. Traversing this tree in prefix order should yield the values I mentioned before.

Comment: If possible, is there something that can be done with the implementation of the tree creator so that we do not have to modify the node class?

Comment: possible, but it would be less readable... is this really necessary?

Comment: Yes, it was originally suggested to me to return a tuple in the recursive helper function to account for the increments, although I am confused as to how to implement that. I am not supposed to further modify the LinkedBinaryTree class and the node class.

Comment: done, see edited answer below

Comment: oh I see that there had to be a double assignment for the tuple. Thank you very much this was very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two issues with your code were:

- you processed the characters one by one while several-digit numbers could be present (fixed by splitting the expression to a list)
- you did not account for the fact that chained operator expressions could be longer that just your standard increment (fixed by adding a `size` property to `Node`

So here is the new `Node` class

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
        self.data = data
        self.parent = None
        self.left = left
        if (self.left is not None):
            self.left.parent = self
        self.right = right
        if (self.right is not None):
            self.right.parent = self

    @property
    def size(self):
        l = 1
        if self.left is not None:
            l += self.left.size
        if self.right is not None:
            l += self.right.size
        return l
```

and here is the new tree creator

```
def create_expression_tree(prefix_exp_str):

    expr_lst = prefix_exp_str.split(" ")

    op = {'+': None, '-': None, '*': None, '/': None}

    def create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos):
        start_pos += 1
        elem = prefix_exp[start_pos]

        node = None

        if elem not in op:
            node = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(int(elem))
        else:
            left = create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos)
            incr = left.size
            right = create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos+incr)
            node = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(elem, left, right)

        return node

    tree = LinkedBinaryTree(create_expression_tree_helper(expr_lst, -1))

    return tree
```

**EDIT** here is a version that does not require to modify the `Node` class

```
def create_expression_tree(prefix_exp_str):

    expr_lst = prefix_exp_str.split(" ")

    op = {'+': None, '-': None, '*': None, '/': None}

    def create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos):
        start_pos += 1
        elem = prefix_exp[start_pos]

        node = None
        size = 1

        if elem not in op:
            node = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(int(elem))
        else:
            left, left_size   = create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos)
            right, right_size = create_expression_tree_helper(prefix_exp, start_pos+left_size)

            node  = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(elem, left, right)
            size += left_size + right_size

        return node, size

    tree = LinkedBinaryTree(create_expression_tree_helper(expr_lst, -1)[0])

    return tree
```